# Rails link_to with ajax remote true not updating view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this little app that has events. In my index view for events I iterate through all events and display some data. In inside the `each` loop I have a link to 'Upvote' a particular event, this is an ajax request. For some reasons my view wont update right away but update when I clicked 'Upvote' again.

Here is my link to 'Upvote'

```
<div id="upvote_link_<%= event.id%>">
   <%= link_to('Upvote', upvote_event_path(event), method: :post, remote: true)%>
</div>
```

This is my `upvote` method where I increment the `votes` field.

```
  def upvote
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    Event.increment_counter(:votes, @event.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end 
  end
```

Next is my `upvote.js.erb` where I replaced the old `votes` value with the new value.

```
$('#upvotes_<%= @event.id %>').html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'upvote', event: @event )%>");
```

Next is my `_upvote.html.erb` partial that replaces the old `votes` value.

```
<span style="font-family:MetaSerifOT-Book;font-size:13px;">
    <%= pluralize(event.votes, "vote") %>
</span>
```

The problem is when I clicked the 'Upvote' link my request goes through and the `votes` field in my Event model gets updated but the view wont update until I clicked `Upvote` again. I am not sure what is going on. Any ideas or suggestions?

**Update**
This is where I set up the id: `upvotes_<%= event.id %>` I have isolated the `Votes` count inside a partial.

```
    <div id="upvotes_<%= event.id%>">
            <%= render 'upvote', event: event %>
    </div>
```

Comment: @rob I have updated the question to show where I set id: `upvotes_<%= @event.id %>`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in controller code. The @event object is not getting reloaded, I think. One solution is you have to reload the @event object either in the view like

`$('#upvotes_<%= @event.id %>').html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'upvote', event: @event.reload )%>");`.

Comment: Hey Santanu that fixed the problem. Thanks a lot. I hadn't seen an example where one has to user `reload`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To add to `Santanu`'s answer, you'll want to look at your method's code:

```
 #app/controllers/events_controller.rb
 class EventsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :js, only: :upvote #-> if you have the responders gem

    def upvote
       @event = Event.find params[:id]
       @event.increment! :votes
       respond_with @event
    end
  end
```

[`increment!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21)